# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS using an .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I was change my ht-access file to

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

when i am coming to my home page example:

`www.xyz.com` it redirect as `https://www.xyz.com/`

my ploblem is when i load  `www.xyz.com/about`  it is not going `https://www.xyz.com/about`
. It showing  `www.xyz.com/about`.
 if any suggection change my htaccess file to work this.

Comment: Do you have more rule or this is all you have in .htaccess? Is `/about/` a directory?

Comment: Are you using some PHP/CMS framework here?

Comment: i am using Wordpress for my Site

Comment: Did you use `https` in WP's permalinks?

Comment: yes i did it but not working

Comment: Open Firebug and check whether you;re getting any redirect in Net tab

Answer (score 0):

Place the https redirect at the beginning. `[L]` tells the apache that this is the last directive, so your line

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

will be the last line that is used.

Comment: I didn't tell you to place this line at the end. Everything after this line will never be parsed. You have to place your RewriteRule for HTTPS (including the RewriteCond lines) at the beginning.